# Form not validating on usage of [ngClass] in angular 2

Tags: html, forms, angular, validation, html-table

I am trying to put validation for empty field as below. But the form is not validating. On adding 3 rows each having 2 columns, error message is only displayed only for first row. Table tag is under form tag. On submit form will go to fetchingFLights method.

```
<div class="content">
        <form class="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && fetchingFlights()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <label>Flight Carrier: </label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <div [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !flightCarrier.valid }"></div>
                        <input type="text" name="flightCarrier" placeholder="Enter Flight Carrier Code" class="textbox" [(ngModel)]="flightInfo.flightCarrierCode" #flightCarrier="ngModel" required>
                        <div class="validation" *ngIf="f.submitted && !flightCarrier.valid" >Carrier code is required</div>
                    </td>



                    <th>
                        <label>Flight Number: </label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <div [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !flightNumber.valid }"></div>
                        <input type="text" name="flightNumber" placeholder="Enter Flight Number" class="textbox" [(ngModel)]="flightInfo.flightNumber" #flightNumber="ngModel" required >
                        <div class="validation" *ngIf="f.submitted && !flightNumber.valid" >Flight Number is required</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <label>From Date: </label>
                    </th>
                    <td>

                        <div [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !fromDate.valid }"></div>
                        <input type="date" name="fromDate"  class="textbox" [(ngModel)]="flightInfo.fromDate" #fromDate="ngModel">
                        <div class="validation" *ngIf="f.submitted && !toDate.valid" >From Date is required</div>
                    </td>

                    <th>
                        <label>To Date: </label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <div [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !toDate.valid }"></div>
                        <input type="date" name="toDate" class="textbox" [(ngModel)]="flightInfo.toDate" #toDate="ngModel">
                        <div class="validation" *ngIf="f.submitted && !toDate.valid" >To Date is required</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <label>Board Point: </label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <div [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !boardPoint.valid }"></div>
                        <input type="text" name="boardPoint" placeholder="Enter Board Point" class="textbox" [(ngModel)]="flightInfo.boardPoint" #boardPoint="ngModel">
                        <div [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !boardPoint.valid }"></div>
                    </td>

                    <th>
                        <label>Off Point: </label>
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <div [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !offPoint.valid }"></div>
                        <input type="text" name="offPoint" placeholder="Enter Off Point" class="textbox" [(ngModel)]="flightInfo.offPoint" #offPoint="ngModel">
                        <div [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !offPoint.valid }"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>

            <div><button type="submit" value="Go">Go</button></div>
            <div><input type="reset" value="reset"></div>


        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: what's `username`? does it mean for `flightCarrier `?

Comment: sorry. Yes that means flightCarrier only. Changed the code.

Comment: hope this example will help. https://plnkr.co/edit/8Mf5drjsXCNwuwkXg4ws?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It worked.
But it is giving me problem. I will be updating the code. The problem is if i add more rows and column it is giving error message for first row only. Also, it is not validating other rows.
 Please help!

Comment: that's because you didn't set validation for the other rows such as `required`. and sorry for late response.

Comment: Than you for fast reply. It worked!

Comment: glad to hear. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && fetchingFlights()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
<table>
 <tr>
    <th><label>Flight Carrier: </label></th>
        <td>
            <div  [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !flightInfo.flightCarrierCode.valid }"></div>
            <input type="text" name="flightCarrier" placeholder="Enter Flight Carrier Code" class="textbox" [(ngModel)]="flightInfo.flightCarrierCode" #flightCarrier="ngModel" required>
            <div class="validation" *ngIf="f.submitted && !flightInfo.flightCarrierCode.valid" >Carrier code is required</div>
        </td>
</tr>
</table>

<div><button type="submit" value="Go">Go</button></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Rahul but if i change to this code the error is still displaying after i enter the values. Also, if i try to submit empty form then there is no validation. Please help!

Comment: Also, i want to validate the Flight Carrier input text box whether it has empty value or not on submitting of form i.e. on clicking Go button.

Comment: Thanks for reply!